# c# datagridview when button click allow user to add rows

Tags: c#, datagridview, .net-4.0

on form load I have set the property `AllowUserToAddRows` to `false`

```
DGV_PatientSessions.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

and at run time there is a button that when cliecked will change the property `AllowUserToAddRows` to `true`

```
DGV_PatientSessions.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
```

but nothing happened anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check these settings

- How data is bounded in the DataGridView 
  Is your datagrid readonly

Also, can you post the reproducible code.